# Directly retrieving text after nested tags in milestone XML

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have run into the type of XML (occasionally called "milestone") that has tags nested in the middle of the element text. This is a very useful representation for parsing of scientific paper PDFs, even though I have seen that it is not following some XML format guidelines. In a simplified example:

`<data>foo <ref>[1]</ref> bar</data>`

Using Element Tree I cannot seem to get the second part of the text (and in general there could be multiple parts with many references), and the only way to even see this text is to use itertext() function on the element "data", but this also returns the text in reference element, which I do not need. Is there a way to get "foo  bar" specifically, or somehow access them?

Just to be clear, the tail is empty and also, I need this to work with several references inserted in a similar manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"foo " is the `text` of `<data>`. " bar" is the `tail` of `<ref>`.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

data = ET.fromstring("<data>foo <ref>[1]</ref> bar</data>")
ref = data.find("ref")
print(data.text + ref.tail)
```

Output:

```
foo  bar
```